# How to include react app inside another app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, components, git-submodules

I am making **two seprate react application** and both are combined as single application at the end.

Consider two apps,

- Sub App
- Main App

Here the main app consists of all sub apps.

**Code for Sub App:**

```js
function App() { 
 return (
   <h1> Here is the code of Sub App</h1>
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.6/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Code for Main App:**

```js
function App() { 
 return (
   <h1> How to implement the Sub App here in this Main App?</h1>
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.6/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Requirement:**

The requirement is we need to include the `Sub App` inside `Main App` like,

**App.js:**

```
import {ComponentName} from "sub-app"

function App() { 
 return (
   <ComponentName />
 )
}
```

**Real world:**

Consider the real world example as that I am having a big app and dashboard is part of it (`Sub App`), So we are about to create that `dashboard` as a separate react app and include the same inside `Main App`.

**Things I tried:**

- Both `Sub App` and `Main App` are different git repos.
- So thought of including the following code in `package.json` of `Main App`.

And tried the following,

```
"dependencies": {
   "sub-app": "https://git@myorganisation.com:<user>/sub-app.git"
 }
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.. I think I am doing something wrong here..

I kindly request you to please help me to include the `Sub App` inside `Main App`.